# Way to fill List<> with elements

Tags: c#

I have in my code

```
List<BookedReelsState> retVal = new List<BookedReelsState>(somesize);
```

Match later in the code if some condition works I need to fill this entire List with same value.

Of course I can do it via `foreach` loop and set values , Is there more elegant way to do so ?
I just to learn something new here .

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
retVal.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(value, somesize));
```

Answer (score 5):

```
retVal.ForEach(b => b.changedProp = newValue);
```

Answer (score 2):

Two things here.

Firstly `List<T>(int capacity)` does not create a List with `capacity` items in it already. It just reserves memory for them. So the list in the example above will have it's length equals to 0.

But if you have a list and want to set each element of it, you can do it like this:

```
retVal.ForEach( rv => rv = desiredValue );
```

Where desiredValue is the value you want to set for each element.

I also find it strange that you want to fill every single element of a list with the same value. If all elements are the same the list serves no purpose, but I guess that you might need to fill with some default value up front, and then change some of them later on.

Comment: Wouldn't `rv` just go out of scope without affecting retVal?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an IEnumerable then you can use [List.AddRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Example:

```
var list = new List<BookedReelsState>(20);

var someEnumerable = new []
{
   new BookedReelsState(1),
   new BookedReelsState(2),
   new BookedReelsState(2)
};

list.AddRange(someEnumerable);
```